# iOS AVAsset integrating with C++ code

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming

**Use-case**

1. Existing C++ code working with stdio files ( FILE* )
2. To be integrated into an iPhone Objective-C app
3. Should be used to read media files from the Asset Library

Is it possible to get the NSFileHandle/Descriptor for an AVAsset object such that it'll be readable using stdio 'fread'/'read' ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, rather than creating an AVAsset using assetWithURL, use [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL].

Comment: how to read avasset via ffmpeg without copying the file to sandbox?